# Django queryset - Adding HAVING constraint

Tags: django, group-by, sum, django-queryset, having

I have been using Django for a couple of years now but I am struggling today with adding a `HAVING` constraint to a `GROUP BY`.

My queryset is the following:

```
crm_models.Contact.objects\
.filter(dealercontact__dealer__pk__in=(265,),
         dealercontact__activity='gardening',
         date_data_collected__gte=datetime.date(2012,10,1),
         date_data_collected__lt=datetime.date(2013,10,1))\
.annotate(nb_rels=Count('dealercontact'))
```

which gives me the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `contact` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `dealer_contact` ON (`contact`.`id_contact` = `dealer_contact`.`id_contact`) 
WHERE (`dealer_contact`.`active` = True 
   AND `dealer_contact`.`activity` = 'gardening'  
   AND `contact`.`date_data_collected` >= '2012-10-01'  
   AND `contact`.`date_data_collected` < '2013-10-01'
   AND `dealer_contact`.`id_dealer` IN (265)) 
GROUP BY `contact`.`id_contact`
ORDER BY NULL;
```

I would get exactly what I need with this `HAVING` constraint:

```
HAVING SUM(IF(`dealer_contact`.`type`='customer', 1, 0)) = 0
```

How can I get this fixed with a Django Queryset? I need a queryset in this instance.

Here I am using annotate only in order to get the `GROUP BY` on `contact.id_contact`.

**Edit**: My goal is to get the Contacts who have no "customer" relation in dealercontact but have "ref" relation(s) (according to the WHERE clause of course).

#### Models

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    id_contact = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True, choices=choices_custom_sort(TITLE_CHOICES))
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255L, blank=True)
    [...]
    date_data_collected = models.DateField(null=True, db_index=True)

class Dealer(models.Model):
    id_dealer = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=45L, blank=True)
    [...]

class DealerContact(Auditable):
    id_dealer_contact = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, db_column='id_contact')
    dealer = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, db_column='id_dealer')
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=choices_custom_sort(ACTIVITIES), db_index=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=choices_custom_sort(DEALER_CONTACT_TYPE), db_index=True)
```

Comment: I am not sure about this, but maybe .extra() can be useful here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

Comment: I tried but the annotate + extra gave me the following error: DatabaseError: (1111, 'Invalid use of group function'). The Queryset adds the "SUM(...)" both into the SELECT clause and GROUP BY clause, which is weired to me. Maybe I can use extra without the annotate and still preserve get the GROUP BY?

Comment: When you use Django ORM, you are not supposed to think in terms of SQL statements. That is not always possible, hence `.extra()` and `.raw()`, but it would be much easier to give a good answer to your question if you explicitly sated your desired effect.

Comment: Could you add your models?

Comment: Well I do not try to think in terms of SQL but I am trying to adapt what seems to be a weakness of Django Querysets, but I hope I can do it simply and that I am wrong. I got the MySQL query above from a simple Django Queryset built first.I edited my question: My goal is to get the Contacts who have no "customer" relation in dealercontact but have "ref" relation(s). Thanks :)

Comment: Could you show us your models?

Comment: I edited the original message to add my models. Thank you very much for helping Ludwik!!

Comment: What do you mean by "ref" relations?

Comment: I mean dealercontact(s) exist with type="ref" and dealercontact.id_contact = contact.id_contact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured this out by adding two binary fields in `DealerContact`: `is_ref` and `is_customer`.

If `type='ref'` then `is_ref=1` and `is_customer=0`.
Else if `type='customer'` then `is_ref=0` and `is_customer=1`.

Thus, I am now able to use `annotate(nb_customers=Sum('is_customer'))` and then use `filter(nb_customers=0)`.

The final queryset consists in:

```
Contact.objects.filter(dealercontact__dealer__pk__in=(265,),  
                       dealercontact__activity='gardening', 
                       date_data_collected__gte=datetime.date(2012,10,1),
                       date_data_collected__lt=datetime.date(2013,10,1))\
               .annotate(nb_customers=Sum('dealercontact__is_customer'))\
               .filter(nb_customers=0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a way you can add your own custom `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` clauses if you need.

**Just use my example with caution** - if Django ORM code/paths will change in future Django versions, you will have to update your code too.

Image you have Book and Edition models, where for each book there can be multiple editions and you want to select first US edition date within Book queryset.

Adding custom `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` clauses in Django 1.5+:

```
from django.db.models import Min
from django.db.models.sql.where import ExtraWhere, AND

qs = Book.objects.all()

# Standard annotate
qs = qs.annotate(first_edition_date=Min("edition__date"))

# Custom HAVING clause, to limit annotation by US country only
qs.query.having.add(ExtraWhere(['"app_edition"."country"=%s'], ["US"]), AND)

# Custom GROUP BY clause will be needed too
qs.query.group_by.append(("app_edition", "country"))
```

`ExtraWhere` can contain not just fields, but any raw sql conditions and functions too.

Comment: It just gives error: 'Query' object has no attribute 'having'

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to get the Contacts who have no "customer" relation in
>   dealercontact but have "ref" relation(s) (according to the WHERE
>   clause of course).

This simple query fulfills this requirement:

```
Contact.objects.filter(dealercontact__type="ref").exclude(dealercontact__type="customer")
```

Is this enough, or do you need it to do something more?

**UPDATE:** if your requirement is

> Contacts that have a "ref" relations, but do not have "customer"
>   relations with the same dealer

you can do this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Contact.objects.filter(Q(dealercontact__type="ref") & ~Q(dealercontact__type="customer"))
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. It seems that Django does not take the filter parameters into account when excluding, so contacts having a dealercontact type='customer' with other dealers for example are excluded. I do not get what I need here.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your requirements. That works exactly the way I understood them. This returns contacts that doesn't have even a single "customer" relation with anyone, and at least one "ref" relation with someone. If that's not what you want please clarify.

Comment: Is it 'Contacts that have a "ref" relations, but do not have "customer" relations **with the same dealer**'?

Comment: Yes, indeed, no customer rel with the given dealer, as for the other parameters given in the filter.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm still not able to understand what you aim for, so I won't be able to help you with this. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Are you not using raw query just because you want orm object? Using `Contact.objects.raw()` generate instances similar `filter`. Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/ for more help.

Comment: Using `.raw()` should be the very last resort. It's defeats the purpose of having an ORM in the first place.