# Django queryset - Add HAVING constraint after annotate(F())

Tags: python, django, filter, orm

I had a seemingly normal situation with adding HAVING to the query.
I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330879/django-queryset-adding-having-constraint) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344182/how-to-implement-the-having-clause-in-sqlite-django-orm), but it did not help me

I need add HAVING to my query

**MODELS :**

```
class Package(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField()


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    packages = models.ManyToManyField(Package)
```

Products:

```
|id|title|
| - | - |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
```

Packages:

```
|id|status|
| - | - |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
```

Product_Packages:

```
|product_id|package_id|
| - | - |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
```

visual

- pack_1 (A, B) status OK
- pack_2 (B, C) status not ok
- pack_3 (B, D) status OK
- pack_4 (D) status not ok

**My task** is to select those products that have the **latest** package in status = 1

**Expected result is :  A, B**

my query is like this

```
SELECT prod.title, max(tp.id)
FROM "product" as prod
INNER JOIN "product_packages" as p_p ON (p.id = p_p.product_id)
INNER JOIN "package" as pack ON (pack.id = p_p.package_id)
GROUP BY prod.title
HAVING pack.status = 1
```

it returns exactly what I needed

```
|title|max(pack.id)|
| - | - |
| A | 1 |
| B | 3 |
```

**BUT** my orm does not work correctly
I try like this

```
p = Product.objects.values('id').annotate(pack_id = Max('packages')).annotate(my_status = F('packages__status')).filter(my_status=1).values('id', 'pack_id')
```

p.query

SELECT "product"."id", MAX("product_packages"."package_id") AS "pack_id"
FROM "product" LEFT OUTER JOIN "product_packages" ON ("product"."id" = "product_packages"."product_id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "package" ON ("product_packages"."package_id" = "package"."id")
**WHERE "package"."status" = 1**
GROUP BY "product"."id"

please help me to make correct ORM

Answer (score 0):

How the query looks like when you remove

```
.values('id', 'pack_id')
```

At the end?

If I remember correctly then:

```
p = Product.objects.values('id').annotate(pack_id = Max('packages')).annotate(my_status = F('packages__status')).filter(my_status=1)
```

and

```
    p = Product.objects.annotate(pack_id = Max('packages')).annotate(my_status = F('packages__status')).filter(my_status=1).values('id')
```

Will result with different queries

Answer (score 0):

Haki Benita has an excellent site that is made for Database Gurus and how to make to most of Django.

You can take a look at this post:
https://hakibenita.com/django-group-by-sql#how-to-use-having

Django has a very specific way of adding the "HAVING" operator, i.e. your query set needs to be structured so that your annotation is followed by a 'values' call to single out the column you want to group by, then annotate the Max or whatever aggregate you want.

Also this annotation seems like it won't work `annotate(my_status = F('packages__status')` you want to annotate multiple status to a single annotation.

You might want to try a subquery to annotate the way you want.

e.g.

```py
Product.objects.annotate(
    latest_pack_id=Subquery(
        Package.objects.order_by('-pk').filter(status=1).values('pk')[:1]
    )
).filter(
    packages__in=F('latest_pack_id')
)
```

Or something along those lines, I haven't tested this out

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try like this with [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery
sub_query = Package.objects.filter(product=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-pk')
products = Product.objects.annotate(latest_package_status=Subquery(sub_query.values('status')[0])).filter(latest_package_status=1)
```

Here first I am preparing the subquery by filtering the `Package` model with `Product`'s primary key and ordering them by `Package`'s primary key. Then I took the latest value from the subquery and annotating it with `Product` queryset, and filtering out the status with 1.