# How can the Django ORM perform an aggregate subquery in a WHERE statement?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I'm trying to construct the following query similar to this the Django ORM:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE depth = (SELECT MIN(depth) FROM table)`

How can this be written in Django ORM notations? So far it seems hard to use an aggregate like this, because `QuerySet.aggregate()` isn't lazy evaluated, but executes directly.

I'm aware that this basic example could be written as `Model.objects.filter(depth=Model.objects.aggregate(m=Min('depth'))['m'])` but then it does not evaluate lazily, and needs 2 separate queries. For my more complex case, I definitely need a lazily evaluated queryset.

---

FYI, things I've tried and failed:

- a subquery with `Model.objects.order_by().values().annotate(m=Min('depth').values('m'))` will result in a `GROUP BY id` that seems hard to loose.
- a subquery with `Model.objects.annotate(m=Min('depth')).filter(depth=F('m'))` will give a `GROUP BY id`, and include the `m` value in the main results as that's what annotate does.

My current workaround is using `QuerySet.extra(where=[...])` but I'd much rather like to see the ORM generate that code.

Comment: Queries are not correlated thus you can compute min by a separate query the do your filtering. And this kind of filter can be called `HAVING` which can be found in SO answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330879/django-queryset-adding-having-constraint  Don't `Min('depth')` your top-level query, you need a separate _subquery_.

Comment: > " and include the m value in the main results as that's what annotate does. "
For this particular problem, you can use [alias](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#alias) instead. It won't fix the "GROUP BY" issue though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Brad's suggestion, this does seem to work as alternative:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(
    depth=MyModel.objects.order_by('depth').values('depth')[:1]
)
```

It essentially becomes this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE depth = (SELECT depth FROM table ORDER BY depth LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```py
MyModel.objects.filter(
    depth=MyModel.objects.annotate(min_depth=Min('depth)).values('min_depth')[:1]
)
```

Using annotate instead of aggregate will keep the queryset lazy.

Comment: That looks pretty close, but `print(qs.query)` reveals that `.annotate()` will add `GROUP BY id` here, so it will just pick the first one. However, `MyModel.objects.filter(depth=MyModel.objects.order_by('depth').values('depth')[:1)` does work then!